# Is there any way to adjust the clock granularity under tmux?

Tags: configuration, tmux, clock

It seems like, by default, the `tmux` status bar clock granularity is set to 2s, however it would be nice to be able to bring that up to a one-second granularity.

Is there any way to set the granularity in a `.tmux.conf`? I haven't been able to find anything about this under `man tmux`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a `status-interval` session option which by default is set to 15 seconds.  This determines how frequently the status line is redrawn.

With

```
set-option -s status-interval 1
```

in your `.tmux.conf` file, this would be would be changed to 1 second.

Comment: That'll do it, the status bar clock's updating every second now. Thanks!

Comment: how much CPU increase usage does it affect if per second refresh? is it worth it?

Comment: @ifelsemonkey That totally depends on your CPU. I haven't touched this option in my own configuration, so I can't really say what the impact would be. I can't imagine that it would be noticeable unless you have a _really_ slow processor.